# Detect customer deletion with shopify webhook content

Tags: php, shopify, webhooks

this is my code but it doesnt work, Im using as shopify delete customer webhook to send info to the endpoint, but the json data doesnt have any customer_deleted object, so how do I check when a customer is deleted from the info sent via the 'customer deleted' webhook

```
$webhook_content = NULL;
$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhook_content .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);

$webhookContent = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhookData = json_decode($webhookContent, true);
if (isset($webhookData['event']) && $webhookData['event'] === 'customer.delete') {
  mail('test@gmail.com', 'deleted', print_r($webhookData, true));
}
```

Comment: what data did you get into the webhook payload, and why did you test `customer.delete` the event name before sending an email into the above code?

Comment: the pay load contains this and no reference to a customer delete object entry:

Array
(
    [id] => 6939090288923
    [phone] =>
    [addresses] => Array
        (
        )

    [accepts_marketing_updated_at] =>
    [marketing_opt_in_level] =>
    [tax_exemptions] => Array
        (
        )

    [email_marketing_consent] =>
    [sms_marketing_consent] =>
    [admin_graphql_api_id] => gid://shopify/Customer/6939090288923
)

Comment: I think it sending the correct data, what do you want into webhook else?